# How do I crawl a site with dynamic forms using WWW::Mechanize?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, perl, web-crawler

I like to retrieve and store the values of an HTML table from a Web site which uses some Javascript and has an URL which ends on `.aspx`, by writing a Web crawler in Perl.

The [Web site](http://www.comelec.gov.ph/results/2004natl/2004electionresults_local.aspx) provides some data on election results.

You have a search form with two options as drop down menus, Province `provlist` and City/Municipality `munlist`.

- You choose the Province. The web page gets reloaded to the same URL and changes the list of available options of the second drop down menu, i.e. City/Municipality.
- Now you can choose your City/Municipality and after clicking the button SEARCH, a HTML table becomes visible with the results.

I like to retrieve all these tables and their results.

I like to do it with Perl, however so far I have only written very small/simple scripts. It would be very helpful if you have some general informations on how I should start this task.

1. I have used some of the `WWW::Mechanize` functions before, only a few though. Can I do this job with the `WWW::Mechanize` functions, are these functions sufficient? Or do I need additional packages?
2. The FAQ for `WWW::Mechanize` states that it has some problems with Javascript. However, in another post I read it may be possible to avoid the this Javascript. Does the called Javascript function for one of the drop down menus cause a problem?

   ```
   <select name="provlist" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'provlist\',\'\')', 0)" id="provlist" tabindex="1">
   ```
3. How troublesome is the ASPX framework?

As I have said before, I only have a little experience with writing Perl crawlers, so any information/hints/etc. you can provide are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's sufficient.
2. The form degrades okay without Javascript. Submit the form once with a different `provlist` item, e.g. *AGUSAN DEL NORTE*, and the response page will have the appropriate `munlist` (*BUENAVISTA*, etc.), and the form will be set to the first item of the list, and the table will have the data for the first item.

Comment: i had some troubles figuring out the order on how to work with the forms() functions, but now it works flawless! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> The FAQ for WWW::Mechanize states that it has some problems with Javascript. However, in another post I read it may be possible to avoid the this Javascript. Does the called Javascript function for one of the drop down menus cause a problem?

If you want to mechanize JS heavy pages, you probably want to look at [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox)